# Why LeakedConnectionCount is always 0 in weblogic?

Tags: java, weblogic12c

Here, You can see the program which fetch the Leaked Connection count from weblogic. But, I always get it as zero. I have set maximum connection count to 10 from my data source and I run some code which not closes the connection so, Connection Unavailable count is increases to 10 but Liked Connection count is still 0.

So, What to do to increase the count of it because there are liked connections are there by application.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.management.MBeanServerConnection;
import javax.management.ObjectName;
import javax.management.remote.JMXConnector;
import javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory;
import javax.management.remote.JMXServiceURL;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

public class Test  {

private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName());
private static final String PROTOCOL = "admin.server.protocol";
private static final String HOST = "admin.server.host";
private static final String PORT = "admin.server.port";
private static final String USERNAME = "admin.server.username";
private static final String PASSWORD = "admin.server.password";
private static final String JNDI_ROOT = "jndi.root";
private static final String DATA_SOURCE = "DataSourceName";
private static final String DATASOURCE_ORACLEDS_JTA = "dataSource-OracleDS_jta";
private static MBeanServerConnection connection;
private static JMXConnector connector;
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Test test = new Test();
    System.out.println(test.isConnectionLeaked());

}

public List<String> getDataSourceNames(){
    return Arrays.asList(DATA_SOURCE,DATASOURCE_ORACLEDS_JTA);
}


/*
 * Initialize connection to the Domain Runtime MBean Server.
 */
 public static void initConnection() throws IOException,
        MalformedURLException {
    logger.info("Inside initConnection");
    InputStream is = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("jmx.properties");
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.load(is);

    String protocol = (String) props.get(PROTOCOL);
    Integer portInteger = Integer.valueOf((String) props.get(PORT));
    int port = portInteger.intValue();
    String jndiroot = (String) props.get(JNDI_ROOT);
    String hostname = (String) props.get(HOST);
    JMXServiceURL serviceURL = new JMXServiceURL(protocol, hostname, port, jndiroot);

    Hashtable<String, Object> h = new Hashtable<>();
    h.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, (String) props.get(USERNAME));
    h.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, (String) props.get(PASSWORD));
    h.put(JMXConnectorFactory.PROTOCOL_PROVIDER_PACKAGES, "weblogic.management.remote");
    h.put("jmx.remote.x.request.waiting.timeout", new Long(10000));
    connector = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(serviceURL, h);
    connection = connector.getMBeanServerConnection();
    logger.info("End initConnection");
}
public boolean isConnectionLeaked() {
    List<String> dataPoolNames = getDataSourceNames();
    boolean isLeaked = false;
    try {
        initConnection();

        ObjectName service = new ObjectName("com.bea:Name=DomainRuntimeService,"
                + "Type=weblogic.management.mbeanservers.domainruntime.DomainRuntimeServiceMBean");
        ObjectName[] number_of_servers = (ObjectName[]) connection.getAttribute(service, "ServerRuntimes");
        int length = (int) number_of_servers.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            logger.info("Server Instance=" + number_of_servers[i]);
            String name = (String) connection.getAttribute(number_of_servers[i], "Name");
            ObjectName[] number_of_dbpools = (ObjectName[]) connection.getAttribute(new ObjectName("com.bea:Name="
                    + name + ",ServerRuntime=" + name + ",Location=" + name + ",Type=JDBCServiceRuntime"),
                    "JDBCDataSourceRuntimeMBeans");
            int pool_length = (int) number_of_dbpools.length;
            for (int x = 0; x < pool_length; x++) {
                String poolName = (String) connection.getAttribute(number_of_dbpools[x], "Name");

                    logger.info("********* PoolName=" + poolName + "  ******");

                    int leakedConnectionCount = (Integer) connection.getAttribute(number_of_dbpools[x],
                            "LeakedConnectionCount");
                    logger.info("leakedConnectionCount         : " + leakedConnectionCount);

                    if (leakedConnectionCount > 0) { // Send email alert
                        isLeaked = true;
                    }

            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.severe("Exception in isConnectionLeaked method");
        logger.severe("Message = " + e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        try {
            if (connector != null) {
                logger.info("Connectors  JMXConnector.");
                connector.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.severe(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    logger.info("End isConnectionLeaked. isLeaked = "+isLeaked);
    return isLeaked;
}
```

}

Comment: Do you have the code that you use to open the connection and not close it for us to see?

Answer (score 0):

The **Inactive Connection Timeout** is set to **0**?

Comment: Yes If I set let say 15 seconds still LeakedConnectionCount is zero.